# Follow A Method

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have some question about difference between "*follow a method*" and "*use a method*":

> 1. During the experiment, he ***followed*** a new method.
> 2. During the experiment, he ***used*** a new method.

Could both be the same?

Answer (score 1):

They could be.  This is just a matter of which is more commonly said.

In AmE, one usually refers to

- **using** a *method*

But

- **following** a *procedure*

Perhaps this is because a *procedure* typically includes sequential steps; whereas a *method* may be more general (as guidelines or rules), and not necessarily sequential.

Consider a simple example.

Procedure A:

1) do this

2) do that

3) do something else

4) do the last thing

Method B:

• record all results on the Lab Notes

• make sure all equipment is clean

• measure carefully

• do not copy from others' Lab Notes

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the difference would be in underlying connotations.

To me, the first one implies an obedient, unquestioning action. The second one implies that the subject made a conscious and rational decision to make use of the new method.